# How to cap a PHP int value

Tags: php, function, math

I am making some calculations with PHP and I don't want a number to be above 100. So, for example I want 50 + 80 to be 100 and not 130. Basically cap any result to 100. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you show us your attempts at doing this, and explain the exact trouble you're encountering?

Comment: I kept looking for the catch in this question.

Comment: How about  `function(x,y) { if((x+y)>100) { return 100;}}`

Comment: @giddy And what happens when (x+y) <= 100 ? :D

Comment: Oopes! =) Well just return the value then. @Gumbo's method is the best. I was just trying to show the OP its just a simple algorithm regardless of the php language.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You could use [`min`](http://php.net/min):

```
min($sum, 100)
```

This returns either `$sum` if `$sum < 100` or `100` otherwise.

Comment: Wow this is some real beauty here. Really nice solution!

Answer (score 4):

You can just use the `min` function:

```
$result = min($result, 100);
```

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to check them I guess.

```
$x    = 80;
$y    = 50;
$z    = $x + $y;
$int  = ($z > 100) ? 100 : $z;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can perform the operation and compare the result with `100` as:

```
$result = 50 + 80;
$result = ($result > 100)?100?$result;
```

Answer (score 1):

do something like:

```
$x = 20;
$y = 90;
$result = ($x + $y > 100)?100:$x + $y;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
$a=50;
$b=80;

$c=$a+$b;
if ($c>100)
{
  $c=100;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function add_max($a, $b, $max)
{
  $c = $a + $b;
  return $c <= $max ? $c : $max;
}
```